# Dataset error -ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

When I using the Table Adapters of a Data Set,I get the following an error in the screenshot as below.What might be the problem?

[image]

Comment: When exactly did you receive\ this error ?!

Comment: if attempting to write a query I get.(after approximately 30-second)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to check your query string to make sure that it is connecting to the database  because the xsd is trying to make a connection to your database and the server replies with time out.